# Center alignment in one NSCollectionLayoutSection

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

I'm curious to know, can I achieve this alignment in only one `NSCollectionLayoutSection`.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziRJ1.png)

My code for the section is:

```
private func createHeaderTagsSection(using section: Section) -> NSCollectionLayoutSection {
        let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .estimated(100), heightDimension: .absolute(Margins.edgeDouble))
        let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
        
        let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1), heightDimension: itemSize.heightDimension)
        let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitems: [item])
        group.interItemSpacing = .fixed(Margins.spacingHalf)
        
        let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
        section.contentInsets = .init(top: 0, leading: Margins.edgeDefault, bottom: Margins.edgeDefault, trailing: DS.Margin.edgeDefault)
        section.interGroupSpacing = 8
        
        let sectionBackground = NSCollectionLayoutDecorationItem.background(elementKind: SectionBackgroundDecorationView.identifier)
        section.decorationItems = [sectionBackground]
        
        return section
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is surprisingly hard to do, but I was able to use edge spacing on the group ([NSCollectionLayoutEdgeSpacing](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nscollectionlayoutedgespacing)) to accomplish this.

It's kind of a pain and won't work for all situations, but what I did was:

1. Calculate the number of cells per row
2. Calculate how much horizontal space those and their inter-item spacing will take up
3. Subtract that from your available content width (don't forget to include any section insets if present)
4. Use that to set fixed-width edge spacing values on the group

Hopefully this is helpful! And hopefully Apple sees fit to make this easier to accomplish in compositional layouts in the future.